# Changing colour of NavigationBar and Barbutton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UINavigationBar`, and the colour of it is `purple`. I have added a `uibarbutton` of the left of it. It too is `purple`, But what i want it to look is `black`.

1.) I only need the `navigationbar` to remain `purple`, everything else `uibarbutton`, `navigation back button` (when we go from one view to another we get a arrow shaped back button) should be `black`.

I used the interface builder to change the colour of the `uibarbutton` (`setTint`), but when i ran it on my `iOS 4.3` device it still appears as `purple`.

I tried cleaning, building and re-installing the app nothing hapence.

Comment: I think you need to use a custom purple image for the bar, and then set the tint to black, because the setTint changes the tint for all the controls in the bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set it up like this

```
// Loads the view
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem* settings = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(settingsButtonEvent:)]];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
  // some more code for your view         

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this coorect ? because you are setting the navigationbar to black, and the button to red. The outcome as shown in the image is the exact opposite. So is it correct? are you missing something ?

Comment: lol coded it directly here and grabbed just a screen from an app I made. It's the correct way of doing so just flip the colours

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a different tintColor for both objects, but you can set an image as the button background.

I hope it helps you!